# Is this group homomorphism well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X = \langle a, b \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle$ and $Y = \langle a, b \mid aba^{-1}b \rangle$. I want to define $f : X \rightarrow Y$, such that, $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b^2$, however I'm having difficulties proving that $f(aba^{-1}b^{-1}) (=ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2}) = e_Y$. Is this even true?

Comment: No it's not true. Why would you expect it to be? The groups $X$ and $Y$ are different: $X$ is abelian and $Y$ is not.

Comment: are the $a$ and $b$ in $X$ and $Y$ the same?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Your question does not make much sense, because the $a$ and $b$ are local to the definitions of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

In $Y$,

$ab^2a^{−1}b^{−2} = (ab)(ba^{-1})b^{-2}=(b^{-1}a)(ba^{-1})b^{-2} =b^{-1}(aba^{-1})b^{-2}= b^{-4}$.

Since $b$ has infinite order in $Y$, I think your map does not work.

EDIT:
Just to be clear, in $Y$, $aba^{-1} = b^{-1}$, a relation I used several times.

This also allows an isomorphism $Y\cong \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$, where

$b\mapsto (1,0), a\mapsto (0,1)$,

and the twisting is by

$((0,1)(1,0)(0,-1) = (-1,0)$.

From this, we can see that $b \in Y$ has infinite order.

Answer (score 0):

No, Let $Z_1=\langle a\rangle$, $Z_2=\langle b\rangle$ be free groups generated by $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then $Y$ is exactly $Z_1\ltimes Z_2$(the action of  $Z_1$ on $Z_2$ is defined by $a\cdot b=b^{-1}$. Note that in $Z_1\ltimes Z_2$, $ab^2a^{−1}b^{−2} = (ab)(ba^{-1})b^{-2}= b^{-4}\neq e$.